# GDM does not start on boot

Tags: arch-linux, lightdm

GDM does not start on boot: I'm having same problem I also read tis problem that you solved before, I tried that but got nothing. Please help me im stuck in try.

Comment: please details what you ve done; a more detailed description of your issue & if you saw here a solution a link to the prévious solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when display managers such as GDM do not start, the problem is the displayserver, which will be either X or wayland.

Since you are using Arch Linux, you should have systemd installed. Thus, you can look into the problem by viewing the journal of GDM by using:

```
sudo journalctl -b -u gdm
```

You need to use sudo, because you want to view the system journal, the -b switch only shows logs from this boot, and '-u gdm' will only show the gdm log entries.

When the problem lies with X, there is still the classic logfile found at /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Look at those logs and try to find a line with "error" or "failed". This will be the core issue.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl enable gdm` as a normal user. You may or may not have to write `gdm.service` instead of `gdm`